# Using of Strfromd/strfromf in C for converting to string without using snprintf : warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strfromd’

Tags: c, makefile

I'm exploring the usage **strfromd, strfromf** functions as an alternative for **snprintf** for converting double, integer to string values respectively in my C code. (I'm using Oracle virtual machine Ubuntu 20.04 version for build purposes.)

I have included

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

in my code but I'm getting the following warnings during compilation:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strfromd’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] during compilation.,
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strfromf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I'm able to remove this warning in my PC by declaring:

```
int strfromd(char *restrict str, size_t n,const char *restrict format, double fp);
int strfromf(char *restrict str, size_t n,const char *restrict format, float fp);
```

at the top of my code (not sure if it is a right way) and warning is resolved with this particular change in my VM but when tried in a different environment, I'm getting error - **undefined reference to 'strfromd'** error and my build crashes.

Does anyone face similar issues while using any of the `strfromd`/`strfromf`/`strfroml` functions and what can be done to remove these issues for code execution?

NOTE:
I already tried below exercise:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The warning is resolved in my VM but still gives an **undefined reference to 'strfromd'** error in the other environment.

Comment: `when tried in a PC in different network` Wait. If you removed the warning by declaring... did it work on "oracle virtual machine ubuntu 20.04" or not? What system is on that "PC in a different network"?

Comment: Those functions are not part of Standard C or POSIX.  If you use `-std=gnu18` (or some similar option, using `gnu` rather than `c`), then they'll likely be declared if they're available on your machine.  They may not be portable, though.

Comment: As I noted previously, the fact that the functions are available on some machines does not mean they are available on all machines — and it appears that they are not available on your 'other environment'.  Until you upgrade your other environment to a version of the GNU C Library that supports the feature, the feature will not be available.  (I'm not convinced that the new functions provide a benefit compared with `snprintf()`, but that's a separate discussion.)

Comment: As the guy who had `strfromd()` added to the standard, it is not intended to add benefit compared with `snprintf()`. The functions exist purely so stand-alone implementations of C, where `snprintf()` is not guaranteed to be present, can be in compliance with IEEE 754, which requires a floating-point–to–string conversion function.

Answer (score 5):

Per [the `strfromd(3)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strfromf.3.html#VERSIONS):

> The `strfromd()`, `strfromf()`, and `strfroml()` functions are available in glibc since version 2.25.

So your system needs to have a version of `glibc` at version 2.25 later.

In addition, [you should also `#define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strfromf.3.html#SYNOPSIS):

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
> [feature_test_macros(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)):
>
> ```
>   strfromd(), strfromf(), strfroml():
>       __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__
> ```

Comment: The OP should also note that [the Glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) says that not all of IEC 60559's features are implemented, though the particular functions they are asking about are among those that are.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding define for `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__`
before inclusion of stdlib.h
like this:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__
#include <stdlib.h>
```

BTW, do not credit me, credit the man page of 'strfromd'

Comment: Some credit is due for finding and posting.